# Is there any anti-forensics techniques to unable text parsing

Tags: file, parsing, text

I would like to know if there is any anti-forensics that unable text parser to browse my text files.
SImply put, I have a text parser that goes through all my text and check all the words.
I would like to know if there are any techniques , maybe by modyfing the binaries, maybe changing the encoding or others, for the text parser not being able to find the words in my text files.
If for example the word : "Test123" is inside my text file, I would like the parser to be unable to identify that word.
But I don't want to hide the word, I want it to look "normal".

Comment: This has too wide a scope to be answered succinctly here, imo. Encryption seems like an obvious answer but there are likely to be others.  You may want to ask yourself _why_ you feel the need to do this?

Comment: Lincoln said: You can break some of the parsers all of the time, and all of the parsers some of the time but you can't break all of the parsers all of the time.